# managing versions npm from git repository

Tags: git, npm

I would be able to manage dependencies using symbols like `>`.

Reading the doc, it seems to be possible https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies

For example this one is working

```
"dependencies": {
    "module": "git+ssh://git@github.com:company/module.git#v1.0.6"
}
```

This one as well

```
"dependencies": {
    "module": "git+ssh://git@github.com:company/module.git#1.0.6"
}
```

But this syntax is failing

```
"dependencies": {
    "module": "git+ssh://git@github.com:company/module.git^1.0.6"
}
```

I have the following error

```
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/ajouve/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/com:company/module.git%5E1.0.6.git /Users/ajouve/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-github-com-com:company-module-git-5E1-0-6-git-0d36a656:    is not a valid repository name
```

my npm version is `3.10.10`

Comment: Are you sure the first two examples are getting the version you request? If you request an *older* version, does it still get the version you request?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Yes but I have two tags with the same version in git (1.0.6, v1.0.6) I don't really know if I have to add the v or not.

Comment: Well, the reason I ask is, nothing I can find in the documentation for git URLs indicates that the #-fragment *does* anything. I would assume, then, that it's a feature of whatever server is hosting your repo, so you may need to specify what that is in your question. In any event, even if a given host provides for `#xyzzy` to match a named ref, I'd be shocked if it allowed for version ranges because git isn't semver-based.